# asp.net web api cannot connect to Azure SQL database with non-admin user

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, azure

So for security purposes I created a different user on my azure sql server so I can connect to it without giving full admin to the server. But it turns out the web api cannot connect with that user. It can connect with the admin just fine. Also I know the password and firewall are fine cause I'm able to connect with the non-admin account through SSMS which got me really confused. For now I just deployed with the master account. But would be good if I could fix this.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice to not to use full privelleges user rather than action based user for each operation like SELECT select_user, Update update_user and so on.

How ever each of these user should be given connection right as well which seems to be not set in your case.
for this go in object explorer
server connection > security > login > 
select your user and right click on it and select properties

in general select sql authentication and mention password and also click on status option and make sure that "Permission to connect ..." is enable and login is also

Comment: be sure that u need to give select privelege to all user.